# NestJS TypeORM synchronizes eventhough Synchronization is explicitly turned off (set to false)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

Sort of out of ideas here. I'm new to the Nestjs (or node backends in general) world and up until anything to di with the db, it's been a piece of cake.

I've turned synchronization off explicitly:

.env

```
TYPEORM_CONNECTION=postgres
TYPEORM_HOST=redacted
TYPEORM_USERNAME=redacted
TYPEORM_PASSWORD=redacted
TYPEORM_DATABASE=redacted
TYPEORM_PORT=5432
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE=false
```

I pull in said .env file as such:

```
const DatabaseConfig = () => ({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT),
    username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
    logging: true,
    entities: [
        "dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"
    ],
    synchronize: process.env.TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE||false,
    migrationsTableName: 'typeorm_migrations', // this field will be used to create the table by name of 'typeorm_migrations'. You can name it whatever you want. But make sure to use the sensible name
    migrations: [
        "dist/src/common/persistence/migrations/*{.ts,.js}" // This is the path to the migration files created by typeorm cli. You don't have to create dist folder. When you save file, compiled files will be stored in dist folder
    ],
    cli: {
        migrationsDir: "src/common/persistence/migrations" // This path will be used by typeorm cli when we create a new migration
    }
});

export default DatabaseConfig;
```

via an "Appconfig" instance

```
const AppConfig = () => ({
    environment: (process.env.NODE_ENVIRONMENT) ? process.env.NODE_ENVIRONMENT : 'development' ,
    port: 3000,
    database: {
        ...DatabaseConfig()
    }
});

export default AppConfig;
```

All pulled into AppModule like so:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    DemoModule,
    CommonModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot(
      {
      isGlobal: false,
      load: [AppConfig]
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule
      ],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return configService.get<ConnectionOptions>('database');
      },
      inject: [
        ConfigService
      ]
      })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

How does TypeORM then on **every** run, create a table with the entity from my entity folder?

```
query: CREATE TABLE "basic_phone_check" ("id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "country" integer NOT NULL, "phoneNumber" character varying NOT NULL, "givenName" character 
varying NOT NULL, "familyName" character varying NOT NULL, "dob" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, "timeCreated" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), CONSTRAINT "PK_3c09423ecba40b5709e30b6061e" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
```

Many thanks

Comment: Overall looks okay-ish. Couple of questions & remarks:
- Why is the TypeOrmModule loaded async?
- You are using typeorm spesific env variables, this is not necessarily the issue, but it can be hard to tell what typeorm does with this, since it will pick this up regardless of what nestjs does.
- The query that you posted is the only table created no matter the state of the DB & config of the entities?
- How do you "run" this? e.g. `nest start --watch` ? 
- Do you have a short summary of tried actions. e.g. reinstalled node_modules, removed dist folder, etc, etc.

Comment: Hi @Funonly, 
as far as I can tell, the synchronous TypeORM forRoot method doesn't give you the option of using a factory like I did (feel free to prove the contrary). 
I agree that it can be hard to tell what it does but I ignored it as it is very unlikely to be the cause of the issue.
No, it's not the only table; TypeORM creates its metadata table as well. It is however the only entity table created as I only have the single registered entity.
I've run it with both nest start --watch and nest start --debug --watch. No difference. Haven't reinstalled nm but have removed dist folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line might cause issue's:

`synchronize: process.env.TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE||false,`

because `process.env.TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE` probably is a string not a bool and `"false"` is truthy

Comment: Actually, scratch my last comment. This appears to be the right answer (odd as I was absolutely certain I had subsituted `false` in for said value before but so it goes). Dodgy js type system. Many thanks!